# How to force webkit to update SVG use elements after changes to original

Tags: javascript, svg, webkit

In the following example, latest webkit browsers do not correctly update the rendering of `use` elements after linked original is updated via Javascript.

http://flooradvisor.com.au/shapes/backend/room/draw_floor.webkitbug.php?room=1&shape=rectangle&design=blocky&rectangle_1=23

Javascript changes original elements to red but webkit doesn't update the clones. This works in other browsers.

I've tried various combinations of the following hacks but they result in my SVG DOM being reset to its original state (colors and viewbox reset to original SVG document values)

```
        /*  Hide and reshow the element (workaround for webkit not updating <use> elements) */
    /*
    svg_el.style.display='none';
    svg_el.offsetHeight; // no need to store this anywhere, the reference is enough
    svg_el.style.display='block';

    svg_doc = svg_el.contentDocument; // get the inner DOM of SVG
    svg_root_el = svg_doc.getElementsByTagName('svg')[0];
    svg_root_el.setAttribute("viewBox", "0 0 2048 2048");
    svg_root_el.setAttribute("width", "2048");
    svg_root_el.setAttribute("height", "2048");     
    */

    var parent = svg_el.parentNode;
    var new_el = svg_el.cloneNode(true);
    parent.insertBefore(new_el, svg_el);
    parent.removeChild(svg_el);
```

Comment: this is a known bug in webkit. i think there is a chromium bug open on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some experimentation I created a hack that works. After updating the SVG I call the following function to force a redraw:

```
function repaint() {
    var svg_doc = svg_el.contentDocument; // get the inner DOM of SVG
    svg_doc.rootElement.innerHTML += ''; // "update" the inner source
}
```

It's possibly worth noting that you can't use the `outerHTML` of the root element. It is read-only because its parent (the SVG document) is not an "element".